# How can I get all HTML attributes with GeckoFX/C#

Tags: c#, javascript, gecko, geckofx

In C# viaGeckoFx, I have not found a method to find all attributes of an element.

To do this, I made ​​a JavaScript function. Here is my code

```
GeckoWebBrowser GeckoBrowser = ....;
GeckoNode NodeElement = ....; // HTML element where to find all HTML attributes 

string JSresult = "";
string JStext = @"
function getElementAttributes(element) 
{
    var AttributesAssocArray = {};
    for (var index = 0; index < element.attributes.length; ++index) { AttributesAssocArray[element.attributes[index].name] = element.attributes[index].value; };
    return JSON.stringify(AttributesAssocArray);
} 

getElementAttributes(this);
";

using (AutoJSContext JScontext = new AutoJSContext(GeckoBrowser.Window.JSContext)) { JScontext.EvaluateScript(JStext, (nsISupports)NodeElement.DomObject, out JSresult); }
```

Do you have others suggestions to achieve this in C# (with no Javascript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property GeckoElement.Attributes allows access to an elements attributes.

So for example (this is untested and uncompiled code):

```
public string GetElementAttributes(GeckoElement element)
{
   var result = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(var a in element.Attributes)
   {
       result.Append(String.Format(" {0} = '{1}' ", a.NodeName, a.NodeValue));
   }

   return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your help Tom but I got `System.InvalidCastException` in line `foreach(var a in element.Attributes)`. Exception is `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Gecko.nsIDOMAttr`.

Comment: I just tested the code with geckofx 29 and and it worked for me. (after updating a minor code typo). What version of geckofx are you using? Are you using a matching xulrunner/firefox version.

Comment: I used 29.0.0.2 version of Geckofx-Core.dll & Geckofx-Winforms.dll.

I updated to version 29.0.0.4. It's OK.